# Why does the ADXL345 (3-axis accelerometer) have a SPI input?

Tags: accelerometer

I have a DE10-Lite board which has an [ADXL345](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl345.pdf) (3-axis accelerometer) on it.

Today I am trying to use it and write VHDL for this driver. I find that the SPI mode has a write function. I think the sensor should be only read because it's translating acceleration into digital low and high.

BTW, the timing diagrams for write and read operations look the same. How do you know when the device is reading or writing data?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I find that SPI mode has write function. I think the sensor should be only read

You forgot to write an actual question, but I think you meant to ask why there is a write function at all.

Look at the register map section. There are many registers which are read/write which can be used to configure the features of the accelerometer, such as tap detection. For example, register 0x1D (THRESH_TAP) tells the accelerometer how much acceleration counts as a tap. Register 0x2E (INT_ENABLE) tells the accelerometer which kinds of events should cause interrupts. Register 0x38 (FIFO_MODE) configures whether accelerometer should overwrite old data when the FIFO is full, or whether it should stop recording data.

> BTW, the timing diagram for writing and reading looks the same. How do you know when it is reading or writing?

See how the first bit on SDI is high when reading, labelled R, or low when writing, labelled /W? That tells it which one you're doing.